# How to draw this path in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, shapes

I'm need to create this shape in WPF. First, I thought is a path, but the lines inside shows is a 3D shape.

How can I draw this shape including the lines?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: You need to make this as 3d object or only draw as 2d image on,for example, canvas ?

Comment: I am not sure exactly how, but take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747437.aspx that might be helpful

Comment: You might want to edit your tags to include XNA tags as to do anything 3d like this, you will need to create it in XNA.

Comment: Wait you just want to draw it in 2d? If so that can be done relatively easy.

Comment: not exactly for XNA. I just want to draw the shape, and their sides must contains a grid in 3D

Comment: But this will be not 3d but only illusion. You can use canvas and add to children collections lines to make shape of the cylinder. For curves lines you could use path or draw it as a sequence of short lines

Comment: This would be a LOT easier in 3D. Trying to draw 3D shapes using 2D drawing tools is very difficult (and silly).

Comment: Drawing the smear on there is going to be difficult in 2D as well; in 3D you could just apply a texture.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The outside/outline of your shape can be drawn pretty simply with Path and Ellipse objects.  The top face of the cylinder can also be drawn with a number of lines (as Path objects) in a grid.  You can just draw them so they all extend outside the top ellipse and use the top ellipse as a Mask to trim them.

The vertical lines in the body of the cylinder are a little bit more complicated.  Their coordinates can be determined by the following formula, assuming the left edge of the cylinder is at x=0 and the point where the left edge of the cylinder meets the left edge of the ellipse is y=0:

```
For i = 0 to NumberOfDivisions
  HorizontalPosition = CircleRadius - (cos(pi/NumberOfDivisions * i) * CircleRadius)
  TopOfLine = sin(pi/NumberOfDivisions * i) * CircleRadius * 0.5 //The 0.5 assumes that the ellipse will only be half as tall as it is wide.
  BottomOfLine = TopOfLine + HeightOfCylinder
  //draw vertical line where:
  //X1=HorizontalPosition, Y1=TopOfLine
  //X2=HorizontalPosition, Y2=BottomOfLine
Next
```

where `NumberOfDivisions + 1` is equal to the number of lines that you want to show up on the cylinder.

MSDN has some good examples for getting started with the [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.100).aspx).

If all you need is just a way to represent a 3D-looking cylinder, without the gridlines, a linear gradient brush and 2 path objects will do the trick:

```
    <Canvas  >
        <Path Width="111" Height="113.5" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="12.5" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 177,190C 176.999,196.903 152.375,202.5 122,202.5C 91.6246,202.5 67.0006,196.903 67,189.979L 67,90L 177,90L 177,190 Z ">
            <Path.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="-0.00454615,0.5" EndPoint="1.00455,0.5">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF28A528" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF63B963" Offset="0.152943"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF9FCE9F" Offset="0.362069"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF006C00" Offset="0.991379"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
        <Path Width="111" Height="26" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FF2CF72C" Data="F1 M 122,77.4999C 152.376,77.4999 177,83.0964 177,89.9999C 177,96.9035 152.376,102.5 122,102.5C 91.6244,102.5 67.0001,96.9035 67.0001,89.9999C 67.0001,83.0964 91.6245,77.4999 122,77.4999 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Ok, this questions intrigued me enough that I went to the trouble of writing a complete article for it on [CodePoject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320744/Drawing-a-grid-covered-cylinder-in-WPF), along with the source code for a simple project to draw the solution.  Normally, I wouldn't go to that much trouble, but this was a nice simple project for me to start learning C#.

Comment: I don't think that's the result he wants, but +1 cuz it's a cool example. =)